# Is it possible to get c# to use method overload of most specific type rather than base type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

If you have a method which is overloaded with a derived type, the method called at run-time depends on the type of your variable, even if the underlying object is actually of the derived type:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass theBaseObject = new BaseClass
        {
            Foo = "FOO"
        };
        DerivedClass theDerivedObject = new DerivedClass
        {
            Foo = "FOO",
            Bar = "BAR"
        };

        Processor processor = new Processor();

        Console.WriteLine(processor.Compose(theBaseObject));
        Console.WriteLine(processor.Compose(theDerivedObject));
        Console.WriteLine(processor.Compose((BaseClass) theDerivedObject));
    }
}

public class Processor
{
    public string Compose(BaseClass item)
    {
        return item.Foo;
    }

    public string Compose(DerivedClass item)
    {
        return Compose((BaseClass)item) + item.Bar;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Actual Output:

```
FOO
FOOBAR
FOO
```

I would like to find a way to alter this behaviour such that the most specific method invoked for a given parameter.

Desired output:

```
FOO
FOOBAR
FOOBAR  // because theDerivedObject is an instance of DerivedClass
```

This would allow specific processing for a bunch of items, all derived from a base.

Is this possible in c#?

---

Edit:

A clarification - in practice there would be no explicit cast, as the items would likely be in a list of collection of mixed types:

Example using a list without an explicit cast:

```
    foreach (BaseClass item in new []{ theBaseObject, theDerivedObject })
    {
        Console.WriteLine(processor.Compose(item));
    }
```

Actual output:

```
FOO
FOO
```

Desired output:

```
FOO
FOOBAR
```

Obviously the cast is still happening - but it's not easy to remove it.

Comment: When you cast it to the base type you're essentially telling it to disregard any of it's own properties

Comment: get rid of the (BaseClass) cast

Comment: I think you may be interested in double dispatch which takes advantage of the fact that virtual member functions are selected at run time (as opposed to the selection of function overloading by argument, which is resolved at compile time, as you demonstrate). The idea is that your `Processor.Compose()` method just "calls back" a virtual function of the *argument*  (which is then resolved at run time to the most derived implementation). This ping-pong is the reason for the "double" in the name.

Comment: @JNF Well, you are telling the compiler which `Compose()` to choose. You do not tell the object subjected to the cast to lose *any* property; it is not altered.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, it's there for using in other contexts, but here it's regarded as the base type. The compiler will not reference it in any way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code reminds me of the [*Haddocks' Eyes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes) poem:

> *But I was thinking of a plan
>
>    To dye one's whiskers green,
>
>   And always use so large a fan
>
>    That they could not be seen.*

First, your code creates a subclass, but then it casts the object back to the base class, so the compiler cannot see the actual type! The overload in your example is resolved at compile time, so the `Compose(BaseClass item)` will be called.

You could turn things around and have .NET resolve the overload dynamically for you by hiding all overloads, and exposing a single method that takes a base class and performs a dynamic cast:

```
public class Processor {
    public string Compose(BaseClass item) {
        return ComposeImpl((dynamic)item);
    }
    private string ComposeImpl(BaseClass item) {
        return item.Foo;
    }
    private string ComposeImpl(DerivedClass item) {
        return ComposeImpl((BaseClass)item) + item.Bar;
    }
}
```

The "magic" is on this line:

```
return ComposeImpl((dynamic)item);
```

the `item` is cast to `dynamic`, which tells the system that the actual overload of `ComposeImpl` must be picked based on the run-time type of the `BaseClass` object.

Comment: Wow, nice. So `dynamic` basically makes it possible to move overload resolution to run time? Looks to me as if that would be hard to implement for a compiled language like C++ with much less run-time support.

Comment: Haha I thought so, but good job I learned something with `dynamic`

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider You are correct, the whole `dynamic` thing required adding even more smarts to .NET runtime, which was from the beginning a lot more dynamic than C++, e.g. due to its support of reflection and emit.

Comment: This is a nice solution because it doesn't require changing the parameter classes (it can all be done in the processor) and when you have a lot of derived types you don't end up with a long list of 'If this then cast that' type logic

Answer (score 1):

First of all the reason you are getting the result you are getting the result you are getting is because of you specifically declared `theDerivedObject as DerivedClass` therefor it will go `DerivedClass` as parameter and with `(BaseClass) theDerivedObject)` you bassically just told the compiler (correct me if im wrong with compiler) or program to take the method with the parameter `BaseClass`

What you want to do is one of the following options

Number 1:

```
public class Processor
{
    public string Compose(BaseClass item)
    {
        if (item is DerivedClass)
            return Compose((DerivedClass) item);
        return item.Foo;
    }

    public string Compose(DerivedClass item)
    {
        return item.Foo + item.Bar;
    }
}
```

Number 2

```
public class Processor
{
    public string Compose(BaseClass item)
    {
        if (item is DerivedClass)
        {
            var derived = (DerivedClass) item;
            return derived.Foo + derived.Bar;
        }
        return item.Foo;
    }
}
```

Or you might want to overide `ToString()`

```
public class Processor
{
    public string Compose(BaseClass item)
    {
        var @class = item as DerivedClass;
        return @class?.ToString() ?? item.ToString();
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Foo;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Foo + Bar;
    }
}
```

If you are not using C#6.0 then Processor will be the following

```
public class Processor
{
    public string Compose(BaseClass item)
    {
        var @class = item as DerivedClass;
        if (@class != null)
        {
            return @class.ToString();
        }
        return item.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange its working for me, I get the result he wants as desired output

Comment: oh, I see, you don't use invocation of Compose(BaseClass item)

Comment: Yeah otherwise it would have lead to StackOverFlow Exception

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Processor
{
    public string Compose(BaseClass item)
    {
        return item.Compose();
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public virtual string Compose()
    {
        return Foo;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public override string Compose()
    {
        return base.Compose() + Bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No wonder you are getting what you get. You overload `Compose` method. You declare two signatures one for base class, another for derived. Then you call the method several times:

- `processor.Compose(theBaseObject)` calls `Compose(BaseClass item)`
- `processor.Compose(theDerivedObject)` calls `Compose(DerivedClass item)`. It happens here that several methods might be suitable for the call. Compiler selects a method having closest base class in the hierarchy which is itself `DerivedClass`.
- `processor.Compose((BaseClass) theDerivedObject))` calls `Compose(BaseClass item)` because you've told him to do it. It has no options to chose from.

You've might be interrested in class **virtual** member **overriding**. See

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public virtual string GetComposeResult() { return Foo; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public override string GetComposeResult() { return Foo + Bar; }
}
```

In this case using following code would do what you expect.

```
public class Processor
{
    public string Compose(BaseClass item) { return item.GetComposeResult(); }
}
```

Comment: That's the double dispatch. I think this is the way to go.