# C#: Getting the compiler to call correct method overload when reading polymorphic objects from an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have an `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` that may contain some objects of type `SubClassOfBaseClass`. I also have an overloaded method with 2 overloads, each one taking either BaseClass or SubClassOfBaseClass.

When I iterate through the `IEnumerable` and call the overloaded method for each member, passing it the member as a parameter, it always calls the overload meant for BaseClass, never SubClassOfBaseClass.

Is there an elegant way to get it to call the correct overload - other then manually checking each member of the IEnumerable and cating it to the correct type?

Example code:

```
public class BaseClass {

}

public class SubClassOfBaseClass : BaseClass {

}

public class Program {
    private static void Method(BaseClass item) {
        Console.WriteLine("base class!");
    }

    private static void Method(SubClassOfBaseClass item) {
        Console.WriteLine("sub class!");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var items = new List<BaseClass>();
        items.Add(new BaseClass());
        items.Add(new SubClassOfBaseClass());

        foreach (var item in items) {
            Method(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting output would be:

```
base class!
base class!
```

...but I need it to be

```
base class!
sub class!
```

Comment: [How to call a method overload based on closed generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491928/how-to-call-a-method-overload-based-on-closed-generic-type), [Is it possible to get c# to use method overload of most specific type rather than base type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770767/is-it-possible-to-get-c-sharp-to-use-method-overload-of-most-specific-type-rathe)

Comment: Why don't you define `Method()` as virtual in `BaseClass` and override it?

Comment: Since your Collection is of BaseClass Type its Narrow Casting behind the scenes - So Base implementation will be called "Always".

Comment: @CodeCaster - thanks for the references. The dynamic keyword seems to be the most appropriate solution to my question. As for defining Method() in BaseClass: That was the first idea I had, but in my specific case (which is different from the basic POC code I wrote above) that might not be the best design.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava - thanks. That is a good explanation of the problem (even though it is not really an answer to my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to post this into the comment section, but I don't have permissions to do that.

However, here is a solution that could work:

According to [dynamic - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic), try to avoid an iteration with `var` - use `dynamic`:

```
foreach (dynamic item in items) {
        Method(item);
    }
```

Hope that helps. 
Good Luck!

Comment: VERY interesting. I knew about the dynamic keyword but never fully understood its meaning. Thank you!